# Grunt JS: passing parameter to grunt-html-build

Tags: javascript, plugins, gruntjs, grunt-html-build

I'm using the [grunt-html-build](https://github.com/spatools/grunt-html-build) plugin to make static site with templates.
I would like to know if it is possible to pass a custom *parameter* object to the *build* function of `grunt-html-build`, like this:

```
    <!-- build:section layout.head(customSettings) -->
    <!-- /build -->
```

to have in template file, like this:

```
<title>customSettings.title</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="customSettings.fbTitle" />
```

Comment: This doesn't seem possible with grunt-html-build , a similar kind of option is present in grunt-bake plugin ( https://github.com/MathiasPaumgarten/grunt-bake#inline-section-statement )

Comment: i've made a quick test with the plugin you suggested to me, and it seems work good for my need. if you make an answer, i will upvote you and make your anwer the one that close the issue. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [grunt-bake](https://github.com/MathiasPaumgarten/grunt-bake) plugin instead , it has a *Inline Section statement*
 which allows for passing custom parameter object , a sample configuration would be

The HTML file where you want to include other content via `grunt-bake`

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!--(bake includes/file.html _section="home")-->
  </body>
</html>
```

The `file.html` file

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>{{content}}</p>
```

The JSON file which contains information about `home` object mentioned in `_section` attribute

```
{
  "home": {
    "title": "Home",
    "content": "This is home"
  }
}
```

Lastly the configuration of the `grunt-bake` task

```
grunt.initConfig({
  bake: {
    build: {
        options: {
            content: "content.json"
        },
        files: {
            "baked.html": "filetobake.html"
        }
    }
  }
})
```